# Create vuefire firebase reference dynamically

Tags: vue.js

I would like to create a firebase reference within a component that includes  a prop passed into the same. However, it seems that within the firebase property of the component 'this' is not bound to the VM as in others. Am I interpreting this correctly? If so can anyone think of a work around? If not, it would be greatly appreciated if an example could be provided.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do within the script of the component.

```
<script>

import Firebase from 'firebase'
import menuItem from 'menuItem.vue'

export default {
    ready() {
        this.menuCatter = this.menuCat.categoryName
    },
    data () {
        return {
            menuCatter: ''
        }
    },
    props: {
        menuKey: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    firebase: {
        menuCat: {
            source: new Firebase('https://bluehill.firebaseio.com').child('menuCats/' + this.menuKey),
            asObject: true
        },
    },
    methods: {
        updateCat(){
            let self = this

                self.$firebaseRefs.menuCat.update({categoryName: self.menuCatter})
        },
    components: {
        menuItem
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. By nesting the menuCat object inside the firebase key, you have shifted the context of this. You can re-assign it, but that's not perhaps the best approach. Personally, I would have a function in your methods hook that returns the firebase object, which you can stash at any point you wish. Also, in terms of concatenating strings, suggest using computed properties - that way your value is already bound to the `this.menuKey` property and it will change as the menu key changes - currently as setup, it will not. In fact, you could just return whole firebase object as a computed property if you like, eg:

```
computed: {
  menuCat () {
    return 'menuCats/' + this.menuKey
  },
  fbRef () {
    return {
      source: new Firebase('https://bluehill.firebaseio.com').child(this.menuCat),
      asObject: true
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  updateCat () {
    this.$options.firebaseRef = fbRef()
  }
}
```

I may not quite have followed your logic entirely, but you'll get the gist.

Lastly, are you expecting this.manuCatter to change when categoryName changes? If so, you'll need to migrate code from your ready() function `this.menuCatter = this.menuCat.categoryName` and make it a computed property `computed.manuCatter = function () { return ..... }` That way it will change as categoryName changes.

Comment: Thanks  I actually took a slightly different path. I used the firebase hook to establish my base reference and then wherever I needed to dynamically work with it I used something like this.$firebaseRefs.menuCat.child(whatever) etc...